# Failure on partial template specialization with gcc 9.3, was working before

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, partial-specialization

I checked [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715375/partial-specialization-failure-with-gcc), but I still cannot understand.

I have this code  (yes I know `<functional>` achieves the same thing) which worked (if memory serves me right, it was gcc6) and now fails with gcc9.3.0

Given these class definitions

```
template <typename D>
class Callback{
public:
  virtual void operator()(D d)=0;
  virtual ~Callback(){}
};

template <>
class Callback <void>{
public:
  virtual void operator()()=0;
  virtual ~Callback(){}
};
```

and these definitions

```
template <typename D,typename P>
struct ParamFunctionType{
  typedef void (*value)(D,P);
};

template <typename P>
struct ParamFunctionType<void,P>{
  typedef void (*value)(P);
};
```

I  have these subclasses

```
template <typename D, typename P, typename ParamFunctionType<D,P>::value f>
class FunctionParamCallback:public Callback<D>
{
    P p;

    FunctionParamCallback(const P& pp) : p(pp) {}
       
    void operator()(D d) { (*f)(d,p); }
};

template <typename P, void (*f)(P)>
class FunctionParamCallback<void, P, f> : public Callback<void>
{
    P p;

    FunctionParamCallback(const P& pp) : p(pp) {}
    void operator()() { (*f)(p); }
};
```

Now the second definition seems a specialization to me (for D set to void), but I get the following error

```
 error: partial specialization ‘class helium::scb::FunctionParamCallback<void, P, f>’ is not more specialized than [-fpermissive]
  297 |     template <typename P,void (*f)(P)> class FunctionParamCallback<void,P,f>:public Callback<void>{
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../helium/signal/callback.h:284:85: note: primary template ‘template<class D, class P, typename helium::scb::ParamFunctionType<D, P>::value f> class helium::scb::FunctionParamCallback’
  284 |     template <typename D,typename P,typename ParamFunctionType<D,P>::value f> class FunctionParamCallback:public Callback<D>{
  |
```

What am I mistaking?

(a MVCE is provided by Jarod42 [here](https://godbolt.org/z/reK19T)).

Comment: I would say gcc bug,  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vqYEEz) works in gcc with C++17 or more, and works with clang/msvc.

Comment: @Jarod42 pls correct if I am wrong with my answer below. Thanks :)

Comment: @NutCracker: It seems to match.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you for the MCVE! I will add a comment to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GCC bug filed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91133) if I am not mistaken.
It is introduced in GCC 7.1.

Comment: thank you, Comment 4 provides the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Following the reasoning of comment 4 of [this bug filing](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91133) provided by @NutCracker I modified the code as follows

```
template <typename P, typename ParamFunctionType<void, P>::value f>
class FunctionParamCallback<void, P, f> : public Callback<void>
{ /*..*/};
```

This prevents the possibly inconsistent resolution for the type of f, and compiles in gcc9.3 without need to relax the checks through compilation options.